# Django form inheritance not working __init__

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form which I want all other forms to inherit from, below is what I have tried but I'm getting an error what suggests the init is not running from the `AbstractFormBase` class. SchemeForm 'should' inherit all the `__init__` arguments before running its own.

Error:

```
'SchemeForm' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

Code **Updated**:

```
class AbstractFormBase(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

class SchemeForm(AbstractFormBase, NgModelFormMixin,):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SchemeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'name',
            'domain',
            'slug',

        )
```

Comment: Advanced Django Forms Usage [pydanny/advanced-django-forms-usage](http://slideshare.net/pydanny/advanced-django-forms-usage) is a valuable doc

Comment: Well, your form doesn't have any fields; a Django ModelForm requires either a `fields` or a `exclude` attribute on the Meta object.

Comment: Apart from that, your `AbstractFormBase` doesn't cooperate with any other classes in the inheritance structure.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I see I need ModelForm on based form, however I don't want all forms to get the same model. guess I could do this with a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AbstractFormBase` class doesn't cooperate with the other classes in the inheritance tree. Your `SchemeForm` class has a specific MRO, a method resolution order. The `super()` call will only call the *next* `__init__` method in that order, and `AbstractFormBase` is the next one (followed by `NgModelFormMixin` and `forms.ModelForm`).

You would want to pass on the `__init__` call to the next class in the MRO by using `super()` in the `AbstractFormBase` class:

```
class AbstractFormBase(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AbstractFormBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
```

Note that the same applies to `NgModelFormMixin`, and that `form.ModelForm` requires that the `Meta` class has either a `fields` or a `exclude` attribute (see [selecting the fields to use](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use).)

Answer (score 1):

Place `forms.ModelForm` on first place in base classes list:

```
class SchemeForm(forms.ModelForm, AbstractFormBase, NgModelFormMixin):
```

and add `object` as `AbstractFormBase` base class and add `super` call in init:

```
class AbstractFormBase(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AbstractFormBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: still not running :( 'SchemeForm' object has no attribute 'helper'

Comment: No, `object` is not required here, but would be nice.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and object is needed here, check your answer)

Comment: @ndpu: no, not when the mixin is really used as a mixin. `forms.ModelForm` inherits (indirectly) from `object` already.

Answer (score 1):

Your Base form needs to inherit from forms.ModelForm

see http://chriskief.com/2013/06/30/django-form-inheritance/

```
class AbstractFormBase(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8's

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('field1', 'field2')

class SchemeForm(AbstractFormBase, NgModelFormMixin,):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AbstractFormBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'name',
            'domain',
            'slug',
        )

    class Meta(AbstractFormBase.Meta):
        model = MyModel   # Or some other model
        fields = ('field3', 'field4')
```

Comment: I have updated my OP based on your answer but I still get the same error, strange.

Comment: Try defining Meta and Fields

Comment: Note that your version still should call the `ModelForm` init! Not calling `super(AbstractFormBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` will still break something.